# how to convert num into words

Tags: javascript, string, methods

this code should return 'One', i need to convert numbers into words.
why this didn't save into strEval?

```js
function wordedMath(expr) {
  let arrExpr = expr.split(' ');
  let arrayOfwords = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'minus', 'plus'];
  let arrayOfnumbers = ['0', '1', '2', '-', '+'];
  let strEval = '';
  arrExpr.forEach((item, i) => {
  let cased = expr.toLowerCase();
    if(cased.includes(arrayOfwords)) {
      strEval += arrExpr.replace(arrayOfwords[i], arrayOfnumbers[i])
    }
  });
  let result = eval(strEval);
  if(result === 1) result = 'One';
  if(result === 2) result = 'Two';
  if(result === 0) result = 'Zero';
  return result;
};

console.log(wordedMath("zero Plus one"))
```

Comment: not sure why you have a for loop since it does nothing

Comment: also this line of code does nothing ```expr = eval(''+ expr +'')```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method is not modifying an instance it's called on but returning a new string. Thus, you need to modify your code in the next way: `expr = expr.replace(...`.
Also, it's a bad code style to rewrite a function attribute, I would rather recommend to use a local variable.
Another improvement would be to use a lookup map (i.e. Object) containing mapping of words to their numerical representation, it will allow to create consistent back'n'forth transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all the code is not scalable at all and this a big problem when you need to expand a little bit.

Please try this off:

```js
const numWords = {
  zero: 0,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  plus: "+",
  minus: "-",
};

function wordedMath(expr) {
  const arrToConvert = expr.split(" ");
  let strToEval = "";
  arrToConvert.forEach((word) => {
    const cased = word.toLowerCase();
    strToEval += numWords[cased];
  });
  const result = eval(strToEval);
  return result;
}
console.log(wordedMath("zero Plus one")); // the result is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this piece of code does not work as expected has a lot to do with the error you should be getting. Which is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` .
Such an error means that the compiler found part of code that's not according to syntax. Considering that the `eval` function runs a given string as a piece of JS code, your string `expr` has some unexpected tokens for JS. If you debug your code you should see that value of `expr` right behind `eval` is still `"zero Plus one"`. That's primarily why your code is not working.

*EDIT*

P.S.
Using `eval` is bad practice in JS. You should consider some other options for your software.